# Can I define a read-only transaction using GAE's JDO?

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, google-cloud-datastore

I'm use the latest versions of the GWT GAE w/ JDO stack.
I have a task queue updating persistent objects with the datastore.
I also have a gwt user interface displaying the save objects (without modification).

Given tightly defined transaction (start/commit) boundaries. Is there a way for me to define a read-only transaction for the GUI that does not conflict with the task updating the objects?

I believe they are conflicting and throwing these exceptions (abridged)

```
javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Transaction rolled back due to failure during commit
```

at org.datanucleus.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:402)
 at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOTransaction.commit(JDOTransaction.java:132)
    ....
    NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
    java.sql.SQLException: Concurrent Modification
 at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreTransaction.commit(DatastoreTransaction.java:70)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the app engine datastore actually uses [optimistic concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) ([more](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention.html)), not locking. that means that a transaction that does only reads will not interfere or cause contention with other writes or transactions that include writes.